# Joining multiple tables in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by

I am joining several tables to create an object that I will use. From the following LINQ you can see the connections and so far it is good. I am trying to join another table SERVICES to CLIENT.

CLIENT -> SERVICE is one to many relationship , one client can have many services. In Service there is a foreign key User.Id from USERS table where I keep my user emails and ClientID as foreign key as well.

What I am trying to achieve is get this object populated. I need to join and somehow group on client and get the ServiceOwners email from every service a client has in a list of strings.

```
    public class ClientEmailContact
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public bool EmailBatchExclusion { get; set; }
        public string ClientStatus { get; set; }
        public int CsOwnerId { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public List<string> ServiceOwnerEmails { get; set; }
    }

    var result = (from c in _dataContext.Clients
                  join ca in _dataContext.Users on c.Id equals ca.ClientId
                  join a in _dataContext.UserSettings on ca.UserId equals a.Id

                  select new ClientEmailContact
                  {
                      Email = a.Users.Email,
                      FirstName = a.FirstName,
                      LastName = a.Surname,
                      ClientName = c.ClientName,
                      EmailBatchExclusion = a.Users.EmailBatchExclusion,
                      ClientStatus = c.ClientStatus,
                      CsOwnerId = c.ClientServiceOwnerId ?? 0,
                      //ServiceOwnerEmails = ??? --------- ???


                  }).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Can you update your question so the terms match the code? There is no table SERVICE in your code.